# Pyarrow read/write from s3

Tags: python, pyarrow

Is it possible to read and write parquet files from one folder to another folder in s3 without converting into pandas using pyarrow.

Here is my code:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow as pa
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

bucket = 'demo-s3'

pd = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://{0}/old'.format(bucket), filesystem=s3).read(nthreads=4).to_pandas()
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, 's3://{0}/new'.format(bucket), filesystem=s3, use_dictionary=True, compression='snappy')
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use s3fs to copy the files?

Answer (score 9):

If you do not wish to copy the files directly, it appears you can indeed avoid pandas thus:

```
table = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://{0}/old'.format(bucket),
    filesystem=s3).read(nthreads=4)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, 's3://{0}/new'.format(bucket), 
    filesystem=s3, use_dictionary=True, compression='snappy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy directly (S3 -> S3) and save memory and I/O?

```
import awswrangler as wr

SOURCE_PATH = "s3://..."
TARGET_PATH = "s3://..."

wr.s3.copy_objects(
    source_path=SOURCE_PATH,
    target_path=TARGET_PATH
)
```

[Reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)