# Is it possible to read parquet files from S3 access point using pyarrow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, pyarrow, amazon-s3-access-points

It is possible to read parquet files from S3 as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043554/how-to-read-a-list-of-parquet-files-from-s3-as-a-pandas-dataframe-using-pyarrow) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513152/pyarrow-read-write-from-s3).

I am working with [S3 access points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-access-points.html). Having S3 access point ARN is it possible to read parquet files from it?

I am trying with the following sample code:

```
import s3fs
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN = "..."

s3_filesystem = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
s3_file_uri = f"{S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN}/examples/example1.parquet"
example1_df = pq.ParquetDataset(s3_file_uri, s3_filesystem).read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

Executing it results with:

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN: Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

I have also tried replacing `/` with `:` in `S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN` which results in:

```
PermissionError: AccessDenied
```

Finally I tried using:

```
pq.read_table(S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN, s3_filesystem).to_pandas()
```

which resulted in:

```
OsError: Passed non-file path: S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN
```

It is worth mentioning that there is no access issues with reading files from this access point, with the code below working:

```
import boto3

S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN = "..."

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.bucket(S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN)
bucket.download_file(f"{S3_ACCESS_POINT_ARN}/examples/example1.parquet", "/tmp/examples/example1.parquet")
example1_df = pq.read_table("/tmp/examples/example1.parquet").to_pandas()
```

UPDATE: S3 access point does not allow non top-level list objects operations:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

But I cannot see any parameter that would allow `pyarrow` to treat the parquet file as a single file, which could potentially avoid having this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue and the error message says: `Invalid bucket name "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:291160143014:accesspoint"` so the actual access point name is stripped from the ARN. I suspect pyarrow only expects a bucket path and does not support access points yet.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-9669

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the S3 Access point Alias, not S3 Access Point ARN.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).